Can a NuGet.Client RestoreCommand specify explictly to ignore all dependencies?
In a standalone C# app that uses NuGet.Client, I'm trying to build a RestoreCommand that restores just a package, and no dependencies at all. I know there is DependencyBehavior.Ignore but I cannot connect the dots and get the RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync to behave the way I want.
So far I've found I can use directly PackageExtractor.InstallFromSourceAsync
